# How can I make objects of the same class do different things in the same function?

Tags: c++

I am making a game in C++ and am wondering how to make 2 objects of a class do different things when the same function is called. What I mean is that I have 2 buttons and when I click one, it should start the game and when I click the other it should end it. This is just a simple example, but basically I want to just call the function click() and the button that you clicked on will execute code different from every other button.

Comment: Put the state (the button number) in the class, and have your function choose what to do with it

Comment: With inheritance and virtual functions _or_ a pointer to a member function _or_ some flag that specifies which operation to perform.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I think inheritance is a bit more complicated than needed in this situation.

Comment: @La-comadreja A simple button class with a virtual `OnClick` member function is not complicated at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is called polymorphism. Check out the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class Button
    {
    public:
            virtual void click()
            {
                    cout << "Button click\n";
            }
    };

    class StartButton : public Button
    {
    public:
            void click()
            {
                    cout << "Start click\n";
            }
    };

    class EndButton : public Button
    {
    public:
            void click()
            {
                    cout << "End click\n";
            }
    };

    void make_click (Button * button)
    {
            button -> click();
    }

    int main ()
    {
            StartButton * start = new StartButton();
            EndButton * end = new EndButton();
            make_click(start);
            make_click(end);
            return 0;
    }
```

The output is:

```
    Start click
    End click
```

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/) you can find a nice tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume, that you are building your own game engine not using a library that actualy handles these things.

What you want to do is register a callback for each function. That is what all the UI libraries/frameworks do. In a simple example:

```
class Button{
std::function<void()> callback;

public:

void connect(std::function<void()> func){
   callback=func
}
void click(){
  callback();
}
};
```

By supplying different callbacks to connect, you can achieve different functionality.

Comment: +1. A `std::function` member is probably the right answer if the buttons have otherwise identical code.

Answer (score 2):

Put a conditional in the function checking for certain properties of the objects, e.g. the value of an instance variable.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a *function object (functor)* or a function pointer as a data member.
Each instance would supply a different functor for the click.

Answer (score 1):

One way is going to be to create an interface(for C++ that is a class with pure virtual methods and a virtual destructor).  Lets call that class clickHandler to go with your button example.  In the click function you call `doclick` on the clickHandler the button has been given.  Now when you create your buttons you give them a subclass of clickHandler that does the right thing.

Other options include using C++'s newly added lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly this sounds like bad design. Pretty much the only way to do this is to pass along flags or state in some other form to the method. But if you're doing that the Button  already has all knowledge about what needs to be done and you might as well create and call separate methods. Alternatively you can give up on your requirement of having the Objects be of the same class and use inheritance with virtual methods. However if different subclasses  have vastly differing semantics for those that might be a sign of bad design as well. So I'd recommend using different methods and explicitly calling them.

Comment: It's no bad design at all. Using callbacks to customize behaviour is a standard pattern. See e.g. answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23301983/280314 how to do this.